# overriding template in magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am new to Magento. I need to override a html file in a project. The project using an extension called 'Amitshree'. I need to override an email template created in this extension in my project. I need a step by step solution because I am not a magento developer. I went through some solutions in this platform, but couldn't resolve my task. The project is developed in Magento 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email templates are located in different modules, let's say you want to override **new order template**.

1. Locate the phtml file, in that case
   vendor/magento/module_sales/email/order_new.phtml
2. Copy it to app/design/frontend/[YourCompany]/[Your_Theme]/Magento_Sales/email.
3. Change whatever you want.

Comment: sometimes magento pics new template placed in app/design/frontend/[YourCompany]/[Your_Theme]/.... folder and some times pics original templates. Why is it so?